# L/GSI vs sortkey begins_with()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any advantage with going L/GSI route that is a subset of sort key to prevent using sort key begins_with?
example:
Sort Key is a composite of field `a` and `b` and `c`.  There will be a frequent query over `known(a)-known(b)`.  Is there an efficiency/cost advantage in putting L/GSI over a field a composite field of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begins-with is extremely efficient. If you can do a Query with that to retrieve a range of items in one go, you’re in good shape. No need for a secondary index to try to optimize further.